# Rails Form Helper - Always have the beginning value for the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm creating a form with placeholders for the user in my rails app.

For one of the input fields, it's currently set up where the user needs to add "http://" every time and I don't trust users always doing this.

I'm trying to create a permanent "http://" and then they could fill out the rest of their url.

I've noticed when I click on the placeholder locally it will disappear but on heroku it needs to be actually deleted as well.

```
= f.form_group do
      .input-group
        input#scan-url.form-control type="text" placeholder="http://"
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear on what your question actually is?

Comment: I'd like to harcode "http://" into the input field so it's always there and the user would just need to enter their url address following the hard-coded "http://"

Comment: It is not possible to hard-code a value into a form field like that. You need to sanitize the submitted value server-side. You are right to not trust users.

Comment: I've had the same issue in many projects and what I've found to be the most effective is just to let the user know that he/she needs to include a URL with a valid protocol..and do a server-end check validating the URL format (must include http or https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way will be to handle it on the back-end (either in the `controller` or `model`). I would do this:

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :set_url

    private

    def set_url
       if (self.attribute[0,7] != "http://") && (!self.attribute.blank?)
       self.attribute.prepend("http://")
    end
end
```

This will prepend `http://` to your submitted string before you save it into the db, allowing you to add `http://` to every time you submit the attribute

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good practice but one way you could do what you want is to put a clause just above this point in your form...

```
if f.object.form_group.blank?
  f.object.form_group = "http://"
end
```

This way if the url hasn't been set yet then the input will contain http:// already (as if the user had already entered it in)

p.s. your syntax might differ slightly as to how to reference the object, based on what f is, but I'm assuming f is a form_builder...

Comment: this will only include it if they form is left blank though, I'm trying to make sure it's always there from the moment they click into the input box

Comment: you could try triggering a function before_save in the model, checking to see if it starts with "http://" and modifying the link if necessary... or you could add a validation in the model to prevent the form from saving if the link doesn't look like you expect... additionally you could attach a listener to the change event of the input via some javascript, but I wouldn't recommend solely relying on javascript for validations...